# What does (its) refer to?

Tags: possessive-pronouns

In a sentence like:
America is a rich country. Its resources are massive.
If the question was: what does (its) refer to? 
And there were choices to choose from: 
A. America 
B. America's

Which one  is the correct answer?
A or B ??

Thank you

Comment: The question should be 'What does _It_ refer to?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ha, yeah, then the answer would be easy!

Comment: "Its" refers to the possessions of America.

Comment: No, "possessions" refers to the possessions of America.

Comment: "Its" means "America's" and refers to America.

Comment: What do you mean by *if the question was* and *there were choices to choose from*? Did you make this up or *was* it actually a question?

Comment: @AndrewLeach - "It" refers to America.  "It's" is the possessive and hence refers to America's possessions.

Comment: @HotLicks No, *it's* is never possessive. You sure can see how, and perhaps also why, it is that  it's its *its* it's confusing people with here.

Comment: @tchrist - Yeah, that was a typo -- I should have said "its".  My fingers get confused by it sometimes.

Comment: The question is ill-formed. In << "Our son is here; he is early": _What does 'he' refer to?_ >>, there are two equally possible answers: the antecedent of the pronoun, the noun phrase 'our son', or the referent (the man himself).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question is very particular about **its**, then I would say that the real answer is **America's**, option B. This is because **it** refers the America, but **its** refers to the resources of America.